# What are layers in the Blue Brain Project?

Tags: neuroscience

I was watching [Bedlewo: Topology meets neuroscience](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vD27zKxoio0) when the lecturer mentions that data is available [here](https://bbp.epfl.ch/nmc-portal/welcome.html). I might find it an interesting challenge to do some exploratory data analysis, but I want to ensure I understand the jargon.

The [download page](https://bbp.epfl.ch/nmc-portal/downloads.html) has some of the data broken down by layers, but I am not sure what a "layer" is in this context. They have a [glossary of terms](https://bbp.epfl.ch/nmc-portal/glossary.html), but layer is not explicitly defined here.

I found the SE post [L1 - L5 layers of the brain](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10375/l1-l5-layers-of-the-brain) that looks like it might answer my question, but I have also been burned by jargon for different things coinciding (kind of like a [hash collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) but for words). Since neuroscience is outside my background, I would rather not assume.

What are layers in the Blue Brain Project (specifically the *Digital Reconstruction of Neocortical Microcircuitry*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One interesting part of the brain is called the [neocortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neocortex). In the human brain, the neocortex is the largest part of the cerebral cortex, which is the outer layer of the cerebrum, with the allocortex making up the rest.

The neocortex is formed of six layers, numbered I to VI, from the outermost layer I – near to the pia mater, to the innermost layer VI – near to the underlying white matter. Each cortical layer has a characteristic distribution of different neurons and their connections with other cortical and subcortical regions. There are direct connections between different cortical areas and indirect connections via the thalamus.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebral_cortex) wikipedia is a reasonable start point for a neuroscience beginner.